# Proftpd cant create folder

Tags: permissions, proftpd

Wanted: Create folder and upload file with *www-data:www-data* user
Current Try: Create folder, upload file with *ftp:nogroup* and filezilla
Result: Even with *ftp:nogroup* can upload file but cant create folder
Action: Try create new folder by ftp
Result: Permission denied

With Debian 9 and ACL enabled without SELINUX.
While installing `WP Hide & Security Enhancer` is necessary a ftp service pointing to wordpress installation.

---

Folder permissions:

```
777 drwxrwxrwx  5 ftp      nogroup  4096 May 30 12:12 /var/www/html
```

---

DEBUG OUTPUT:

```
dispatching PRE_CMD command 'MKD myNewFolder' to mod_exec  
dispatching PRE_CMD command 'MKD myNewFolder' to mod_rewrite  
dispatching PRE_CMD command 'MKD myNewFolder' to mod_tls  
dispatching PRE_CMD command 'MKD myNewFolder' to mod_core  
dispatching PRE_CMD command 'MKD myNewFolder' to mod_core  
dispatching PRE_CMD command 'MKD myNewFolder' to mod_quotatab  
dispatching CMD command 'MKD myNewFolder' to mod_core  
in dir_check(): setting umask to 0666 (was 0666)  

chmod(/.abcDEFGHIJKLM) failed: Permission denied  

dispatching POST_CMD_ERR command 'MKD myNewFolder' to mod_exec  
dispatching POST_CMD_ERR command 'MKD myNewFolder' to mod_quotatab  
dispatching LOG_CMD_ERR command 'MKD myNewFolder' to mod_log  
dispatching PRE_CMD command 'MKD /myNewFolder' to mod_exec  
dispatching PRE_CMD command 'MKD /myNewFolder' to mod_rewrite  
dispatching PRE_CMD command 'MKD /myNewFolder' to mod_tls  
dispatching PRE_CMD command 'MKD /myNewFolder' to mod_core  
dispatching PRE_CMD command 'MKD /myNewFolder' to mod_core  
dispatching PRE_CMD command 'MKD /myNewFolder' to mod_quotatab  
dispatching CMD command 'MKD /myNewFolder' to mod_core  
in dir_check(): setting umask to 0666 (was 0666)  

chmod(/.abcDEFGHIJKLM) failed: Permission denied  

dispatching POST_CMD_ERR command 'MKD /myNewFolder' to mod_exec  
dispatching POST_CMD_ERR command 'MKD /myNewFolder' to mod_quotatab  
dispatching LOG_CMD_ERR command 'MKD /myNewFolder' to mod_log  

scrubbing scoreboard  
ROOT PRIVS at scoreboard.c:1541  
RELINQUISH PRIVS at scoreboard.c:1544  
ROOT PRIVS at scoreboard.c:1575  
RELINQUISH PRIVS at scoreboard.c:1681  
finished scrubbing scoreboard
```

---

proftpd.conf:

```
Include /etc/proftpd/modules.conf  
UseIPv6 off  
IdentLookups off  
ServerName "myServerName"  
ServerType standalone  
DeferWelcome off  
MultilineRFC2228 on  
DefaultServer on  
ShowSymlinks on  
TimeoutNoTransfer 600  
TimeoutStalled 600  
TimeoutIdle 1200  
DisplayLogin welcome.msg  
DisplayChdir .message true  
ListOptions "-l"  
DenyFilter \*.*/  
DefaultRoot /var/www/html  
RequireValidShell off  
Port 21  
<IfModule mod_dynmasq.c></IfModule>  
MaxInstances 30  
User ftp  
Group nogroup  
Umask 666 666  
AllowOverwrite on  
TransferLog /var/log/proftpd/xferlog  
SystemLog /var/log/proftpd/proftpd.log  
<IfModule mod_quotatab.c>  
    QuotaEngine off  
</IfModule>  
<IfModule mod_ratio.c>  
    Ratios off  
</IfModule>  
<IfModule mod_delay.c>  
    DelayEngine on  
</IfModule>  
<IfModule mod_ctrls.c>  
    ControlsEngine off  
    ControlsMaxClients 2  
    ControlsLog /var/log/proftpd/controls.log  
    ControlsInterval 5  
    ControlsSocket /var/run/proftpd/proftpd.sock  
</IfModule>  
<IfModule mod_ctrls_admin.c>  
    AdminControlsEngine off  
</IfModule>  
<Anonymous /var/www/html>  
    User ftp  
    Group nogroup  
    UserAlias anonymous ftp  
    DirFakeUser on ftp  
    DirFakeGroup on ftp  
    RequireValidShell off  
    MaxClients 10  
    DisplayLogin welcome.msg  
    DisplayChdir .message  
    <Directory *>  
        <Limit WRITE READ>  
            AllowAll  
        </Limit>  
    </Directory>  
    <Directory incoming>  
        Umask 022 022  
        <Limit READ WRITE>  
            AllowAll  
        </Limit>  
        <Limit STOR CWD MKD RMD DELE XRMD XMKD>  
            AllowAll  
        </Limit>  
    </Directory>   
</Anonymous>  
Include /etc/proftpd/conf.d/
```

[Proftpd cant create folder](https://github.com/proftpd/proftpd/issues/721)

Comment: Are you using SELinux ? Check with getenforce

Comment: Following the commands I did:

Comment: sudo getenforce => bash: getenforce: command not found

Comment: sudo /usr/sbin/getenforce => sudo: /usr/sbin/getenforce: command not found

Comment: sudo sestatus => sudo: sestatus: command not found

Comment: sudo cat /etc/sysconfig/selinux => cat: /etc/sysconfig/selinux: No such file or directory

Comment: Then it is not an SELinux issue , one thing excluded from your debugging

Comment: Debian 9 with ACL enabled